# Can't verify OAuth1 signature sent by Moodle

Tags: oauth, ocaml, moodle, hmacsha1, lti

Good morning.

I'm trying to implement OAuth1 authentification in OCaml to get secure LTI request with Moodle.
I have some trouble when I want to rebuild the OAuth1 signature : it doesn't match with the signature Moodle sent me in the POST's payload.

I made manually the build of OAuth's signature following the [twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature) documentation and the [OAuth core](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) specification.

Here is my function :

```
let signature_oauth liste_args http_method basic_uri consumer_key secret =
    let couple_encode = (* 1 : encode keys/values *)
      List.map (
          fun (k,v) -> (Netencoding.Url.encode ~plus:false k, Netencoding.Url.encode ~plus:false v))
      @@ convert_to_gapi liste_args
    in
    let couple_trie =   (* 2 : sort by key [and value] *)
      List.sort   
        (fun (k1, v1) (k2,v2) ->
          let res = compare k1 k2 in
          if res = 0 then compare v1 v2 else res) couple_encode
    in 
    let liste_concat =  (* 3 : key=value&key2=value2 *)
      String.concat "&"
      @@ List.map
           (fun (k,v) -> k ^ "=" ^ v) couple_trie
    in 
    let signature_base_string =     (* 4 :add HTTP_method and uri *)
      sprintf "%s&%s&%s" (String.uppercase_ascii http_method) (Netencoding.Url.encode ~plus:false basic_uri) (Netencoding.Url.encode ~plus:false liste_concat)
    in
    let signing_key = (Netencoding.Url.encode ~plus:false consumer_key) ^ "&" ^ (Netencoding.Url.encode ~plus:false secret) in  (* 5 : Créer la signing_key *)
    let encodage = Netencoding.Base64.encode
                   @@ Cstruct.to_string
                   @@ Nocrypto.Hash.SHA1.hmac (Cstruct.of_string signing_key) (Cstruct.of_string signature_base_string)
    in
   encodage
```

- My function call : `signature_oauth liste_args "post" "localhost:8000/launch" !oauth_consumer_key my_secret`
- The *liste_args* argument is the the payload splitted by "&" (Ex : [oauth_version=1.0;oauth_nonce=5aa374e2728914002261bbb7b4bd8e3e];...).
- The convert_to_gapi function convert this *liste_args* in liste of couple (Ex : [(oauth_version,1.0);(oauth_nonce,5aa374e2728914002261bbb7b4bd8e3e);...]. It also **remove** the *oauth_signature*.
- The payload is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* encoded.

Here is an example of a payload I can receive :

```
oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=5aa374e2728914002261bbb7b4bd8e3e&oauth_timestamp=1588583843&oauth_consumer_key=rfrezFZErzfzHJmpmkBFT&user_id=2&lis_person_sourcedid=&roles=Instructor%2Curn%3Alti%3Asysrole%3Aims%2Flis%2FAdministrator%2Curn%3Alti%3Ainstrole%3Aims%2Flis%2FAdministrator&context_id=2&context_label=CT&context_title=Cours+test&resource_link_title=Test&resource_link_description=&resource_link_id=2&context_type=CourseSection&lis_course_section_sourcedid=1&lis_result_sourcedid=%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22instanceid%22%3A%222%22%2C%22userid%22%3A%222%22%2C%22typeid%22%3A%221%22%2C%22launchid%22%3A2096392689%7D%2C%22hash%22%3A%225dbc6bff5ec32c9eee91ee3dcb476b3a553ae5337f8a21b3876b52e4e6cf862c%22%7D&lis_outcome_service_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmod%2Flti%2Fservice.php&lis_person_name_given=Admin&lis_person_name_family=User&lis_person_name_full=Admin+User&ext_user_username=user&lis_person_contact_email_primary=user%40example.com&launch_presentation_locale=en&ext_lms=moodle-2&tool_consumer_info_product_family_code=moodle&tool_consumer_info_version=2019111802&oauth_callback=about%3Ablank&lti_version=LTI-1p0&lti_message_type=basic-lti-launch-request&tool_consumer_instance_guid=localhost&tool_consumer_instance_name=%22New+Site%22&tool_consumer_instance_description=%22New+Site%22&launch_presentation_document_target=iframe&launch_presentation_return_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmod%2Flti%2Freturn.php%3Fcourse%3D2%26launch_container%3D3%26instanceid%3D2%26sesskey%3DPPPY9j3N8D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=fuB7Qm0MXLrHPrvniQsBNcvj7BA%3D
```

I tried to make the OAuth1 signature with a [librairie](https://github.com/astrada/gapi-ocaml/blob/beta/src/gapi/gapiOAuth1.ml) but I got the same signature as my function.

I guess I am missing something in the creation of signature.

I'm building the signature with the same parameters as Moodle (sent in the payload), using the same *secret key* and the same algorithm.

- In the OAuth1's documentation I read they didn't use *oauth_callback* in the payload but Moodle does.
  Should I remove it ?
- They talk of an *oauth_token* too. But Moodle didn't give me one and I didn't have a clue of how getting it. It is essential to build the signature ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
It had 2 errors :

First one was the *signing_key* : I only need to make `(Netencoding.Url.encode ~plus:false secret) ^ "&"`

The other was from Moodle : when you configure an "Automatic tool, based on tool URL" and then switch to a *Course Tool*, Moodle doesn't care about the Course Tool's configuration. You need first to delete all the fields of the Automatic tool and then switch to your *Course Tool*.

What helped me to understand:

- http://lti.tools/saltire/
- https://sandbox.moodledemo.net/
- http://lti.tools/oauth/